# Getting crash in SwiftData - Relationship(.cascade)

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I tried retrieve value from this model object. getting crash here.

Here I didn't insert any data in table. but I init a new object in variable and getting the default values to local @State variables.

[image]

```
    @Model
final class CompanyDetail: Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
    
    @Attribute(.unique) var id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var dateOfJoin: Date = Date.now
    var workingHours: String = ""
    var weeklyWorkingDays: String = ""
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String, dateOfJoin: Date, workingHours: String, weeklyWorkingDays: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.dateOfJoin = dateOfJoin
        self.workingHours = workingHours
        self.weeklyWorkingDays = weeklyWorkingDays
    }
    
    init() {}

    var description: String {
        String(format: "id: %@, name: %@, DoJ: %@, workingHours: %@, weeklyWorkingDays: %@", id.description, name, dateOfJoin.description, workingHours, weeklyWorkingDays)
    }
}
```

Retrieving value

```
 let myDetail = UserDetail()
        
        self.userName = myDetail.name
        self.dob = myDetail.dateOfBirth
        
        self.email = myDetail.email
        self.mobileNumber = myDetail.mobile
        
        if let company = myDetail.company {
            self.companyName = company.name
            self.joinedDate = company.dateOfJoin
            
            self.workingHours = company.workingHours
            self.workingDays = company.weeklyWorkingDays
        }
```

Comment: You should include all code as text and what is the error you get when it's crashing?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right the:
why not just use:
Text("Description:  (username) (date)") //and so .. just continue with  formatting

```
var description : String {
   String(format: "name: %@", "is",name , "%@%x", "DoJ in Hex: ", dateOfJoin as CVarArg)
   // why use NSString stringWithFormat when swift +5 have string interpolation??
```

}
Make a View

```
struct UserDetailView: View {
@State var username : String
@State var date : Date
@State var email : String
@State var mobilenumber : String

var body: some View {
    
    
        TextField("username", text: $username)
        DatePicker("BirthDate", selection: $date)
   
        TextField("Email", text: $email)
    TextField("MobileNumber", text: $mobilenumber)
   
}
```

then call: UserDetailView(username: username, date: date, email: email, mobilenumber: mobilenumber)

```
struct ContentView: View {
@Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
@Query private var mydetails: [CompanyDetail]

@State var username : String
@State var date : Date
@State var email : String
@State var mobilenumber : String
```